# How to offset caption?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I have a large table, so I use `\pdfpagewidth=16in \pdfpageheight=8in` to enlarge the page to fit my table. However, I cannot center my captions (one above and one below the table). I am using `tabularx` as well. How can I center my captions? Thank you.

```
\usepackage{caption,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\pdfpagewidth=16in \pdfpageheight=8in
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabularx}{14in}{lcccccccccccc} \hline\hline
Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption*{\\Test.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a *full* (compilable) code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the page size should be your last resort because there are much safer alternatives you can initially think of. There is the `sidewaystable` from the `rotating` package, there is `\begin{landscape} ... \end{landscape}` from the `pdflscape` package, using `\small`er but readable text or setting `\tabcolsep` to a minimum is also an option, etc.

But if you have to, then using a package will be desirable. The `geometry` package, sadly, can not change the page dimensions midway in the document, so, we can use the `typearea` package. The latter will take care of different components of the page like headers, footers, etc. Unlike `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight`, setting the page dimensions with `typearea` will change `\linewidth` accordingly. This is the main reason why `centering` didn't work in your example above.

So, in your case, you can issue:

```
\KOMAoptions{paper=16in:8in}
\areaset{14in}{7in}
\recalctypearea
```

to set the required width and height. You may get some warnings but you can fine tune the settings to eliminate these warnings. Then you should restore the original page dimensions by issuing:

```
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4} % or letter, a3, a1, etc.
\areaset{<orig. width>}{<orig. height>}
\recalctypearea
```

after the end of your table.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage{caption,tabularx}
\begin{document}

\KOMAoptions{paper=16in:8in}
\areaset{14in}{7in}
\recalctypearea

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lcccccccccccX} \hline\hline
Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word & Word \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption*{\\Test.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]